# How to replace all strings '?' with a 0 float?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I am cleaning a data frame currently and am running into issues because all of them are a mix of int and str, but I am trying to convert all of them to floats. The data frame is all numbers as well as some entries with '?' strings that I am trying to replace with '0' floats. How should I go about doing so?

```
    # Load the data from the file
    df = pd.read_csv('processed.state.csv')
    df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Yields an error:
Unable to parse string "?" at position 165

Comment: `df.replace("?", 0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,23,'1','2', "?"])
df.replace('?', 0).apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

A more generic solution to replace non-numbers to 0 will be

```
def fun(x):
  try:
    return float(x)
  except ValueError:
    return 0

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1,23,'1','2', "?"], 'c2': [1,23,'abc','2', "?"]})

df.applymap(fun)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function:

```py
def to_float(item):
    try:
        return float(item)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

And apply that to the DataFrame instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('processed.state.csv' encoding = 'utf-8')
df.replace('?', 0)
df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: Did you try to add encoding='utf8'? Like: df = pd.read_csv('processed.state.csv', encoding='utf8')

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda x: 0.0 if x == '?' else x).astype(np.float64)
```